# Kendo pie chart displays only empty area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, pie-chart

Despite all the searchs on the internet. I can't find what's wrong with my code.
I'm just trying to populate my pie with data from my database. Here is my code:

DataAccess function:
(this is here i get all the data to populate my pie)

```
   public static IEnumerable<PieModel> getTypesForStatistics()
    {
        var dbo = new UsersContext();
        var all = (from a in dbo.Note
                      select a).ToList();
        var results = all.GroupBy(item => item.language.lang)
                         .Select(g => new PieModel
                         {
                             Language = g.Key,
                             Count = g.Count()
                         });
        return results.ToList();

    }
```

And the model i have created:

```
   public class PieModel
    {
        public string Language { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        // example : English,4 | Spanish,16 | German, 2 etc
    }
```

In my controller :

```
  public class StatisticsController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Statistics/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();      
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult displayChart()
        {
            var results = Json(DAL.StatisticsAccess.getTypesForStatistics()); 
            return Json(results);
        }

    }
```

And finally my view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<DevelopmentNotesProject.Models.PieModel>()
        .Name("chart")
                .Title(title => title
                    .Text("")
                    .Position(ChartTitlePosition.Bottom))
        .Legend(legend => legend
            .Visible(false)
        )
                   .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("displayChart", "Statistics")))
            .Series(series =>
            {
                series.Pie( model => model.Count,model => model.Language);
            })
        .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
            .Visible(true)
            .Format("{0}%")
        )


    )
```

Thanks in advance for the time you'll take reading my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution doing things a different way :

Controller :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable <PieModel> pieModel = DAL.StatisticsAccess.getTypesForStatistics();
    return View(pieModel);      
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult displayChart() // no longer used
{
    var results = Json(DAL.StatisticsAccess.getTypesForStatistics()); 
    return Json(results);
}
```

view :

```
@model IEnumerable<DevelopmentNotesProject.Models.PieModel>
..
...
....
    @(Html.Kendo().Chart(Model)
        .Name("chart")
                .Title(title => title
                    .Text("")
                    .Position(ChartTitlePosition.Bottom))
        .Legend(legend => legend
            .Visible(false)
        )
                   //.DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("displayChart", "Statistics")))
            .Series(series =>
            {
                series.Pie( model => model.Count,model => model.Language);
            })




        .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
            .Visible(true)
            .Format("{0}%")
        )


    )
```